# a reference request to study properties of a set which is closed under a binary operation

Tags: reference-request, elementary-set-theory

Let $S$ be a collection of disjoint sets. Let a binary operation '*' defined $\forall x,y$ each belonging to two different sets or a same set in $S$ with the property that $z=x*y$ belongs to some set in $S$ . Let $\forall A_1,A_2 \in S$ a  binary operation $ \otimes$ is defined between $A_1,A_2$ as $B=A_1 \otimes A_2$ as the collection of all $z=(x*y)$ where $x\in A_1,y\in A_2$. Now the set $S$ is closed under the binary operation $\otimes$.

I want to study the properties of such a set $S$ under the operation $\otimes$.My question is what is the subject in mathematics which deals with such a situation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sets with a binary operation that is not assumed to be associative are called [Magmas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_%28algebra%29) (they are sometimes also called "quasigroups", especially in older literature, but that term has a different meaning in category Theory). Your set $S$ with operation $\otimes$ is a magma.

If the operation happens to be associative, then you have [semigroup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup), though that will depend, in this case, on the binary operation *.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the pains to insert links.